# How can I have two users working in one session on Windows 2008 R2 over RDP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, vps, rdp

I'm looking for a way where two users can work off one VPS running Windows 2008 R2. The goal is to have all of the programs being shared, and viewed together - I guess like remote control. They need to both be able to log in/log out and pickup where they left off.

I've enabled multiple RDP connections to one user, and I've tried using Remote desktop where Admin1 starts a session, and Admin2 will remote control Admin1. This works until Admin1 logs off, which disconnects Admin2 from the session.

The point is, I need a session to be logged in 24/7 by a user so that my automation program can work 24/7 (it requires the GUI to be present so that it can perform automatic mouse clicks and such).

Comment: This may seem odd, but you can do this if you run XenServer to host your guests.  If each admin has a copy of XenCenter on their PCs, then the console in XenCenter will function much like what you want.

Comment: I'd like to use RDP as I can login to the server from my iPhone or iPad to check up on things. I have VPS1 (main vps), and VPS2. I will try and login to VPS1 from VPS2 over vnc to keep a live connection 24/7. Then, I will connect at my leisure to VPS1 via RDP (from my iPhone for example). I'm hoping this won't disturb the session.. I might actually have to try it the other way around.. vnc/rdp

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need a different protocol instead of (or in addition to) RDP.

If you're dead-set on RDP, see if you can get the remote assistance feature working, which should do most of what you want.

If you're not dead-set on RDP, use a different protocol, such as VNC, to share the screen.

Answer (score -1):

How about creating a local user which logs on (automaticly or not, as you like), allow multiple login and set incomming connections to use the session of this local user?

For security you could restrict this user kinda hard. So if you wan't to do some work where you need to be admin it will ask you for an admin-authetification. And if someone could ever be able to log into this account, he still has no rights to do silly stuff.

I haven't tested it yet.

And i guess HopelessN00bs answer might be better, because you do not have to mess around with the security Problems my purpose would bring along.